# Commutant of a von Neumann algebra as the linear span of unitaries.

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm reading chapter 4 of Gerard Murphy's C*-algebras book and am confused by a statement in his proof of theorem 4.1.10. In his proof, he says, "$A'$ is the linear span of its unitaries" (where $A'$ denotes the commutant of $A$). I can't find any reference to why this is true anywhere earlier in the chapter. Am I missing something, or is this referring to some other result?

For context, 4.1.10 states:

> Let $A$ be a von Neumann algebra on a Hilbert space $H$ and $v$ an element of $A$ with polar decomposition $v = u|v|$. Then $u \in A$.

Comment: Does Murphy show in a previous chapter (perhaps an exercise) that in a unital C*-algebra, every element is a linear combination of 4 unitary elements?  (If $x=x^*$ and $\|x\|\leq 1$, then $x\pm i\sqrt{1-x^2}$ are unitary and $x$ is their average$.)  $A'$ is a unital C*-algebra.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Murphy showed decomposition into hermitian elements and into positive elements and that has been used heavily in the last chapter. However, I don't recall coming across that decomposition into unitaries (and I have done all the HW problems). Thanks for providing it, I figured I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 6):

See Remark 2.2.2 on p.45 of Murphy's book.  There he shows every element in a unital C*-algebra may be written as a linear combination of four unitary elements.